# A simple way to get page full of 2 choice radio buttons side to side on a list form - SPD 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

Scoured through some solutions but can't seem to find a simple way to get a list form page full of 2 choice radio buttons lined up horizontally.
Anyone know if a simple solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into **SPServices**? This jQuery library has some nifty functions such as [SPArrangeChoices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipagehttp://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPArrangeChoices&referringTitle=Documentation).

To use this you can add an extra webpart to the form, a content editor webpart. In this webpart you can put HTML code, in this case script tags to include first jQuery then SPServices. Then another to call the arrange function referenced earlier.

Another option is to put the JS into the form webpart itself but I like the content editor webpart approach best.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/11/arrange-choice-field-radio-buttons-horizontally-in-sharepoint.html

Comment: Does this also apply to SP2010?

Comment: yes..it is using client side scripts and you can have it for 2010 as well

Answer (score 0):

Edit the list form using Infopath and add a 2 column table with as many rows as you like to fill the page. insert Radio buttons into each of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are saying you want to change the layout and layout means CSS.
To override the SharePoint default form styles You can either:

- Add a Content Editor Webpart on the page with the needed override CSS
- set a web / site level CSS file if you want it to happen on every form.

Use your browser's debugger (F12) to determine the styles to be overridden. If any style is defined inline, use the !important switch in your CSS.

Comment: Thank you everyone I apologize for the late reply. I wish I could give everyone the deserved thanks as points. I am truly grateful..